# wordpress all post filter by year

Tags: php, functions, javascript

WordPress all post filter by year does not work please help us
my code is
when i select 2016 for see old post page is reloded bt 2016 post nor show

See this page 
http://w3ondemand.com/dev/itim/%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA/test-pagination/

```
<div class="filter-by">
    <?php
        $selected = '';
        if (isset($_GET['doc_year'])) {
        $selected = '&selected=' . $_GET['doc_year'];
        }

        wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=בחר שנה&name=year&taxonomy=years&orderby=name&order=DESC' . $selected);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("year");
    function onCatChange() {
    if (dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0) {
    location.href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>/?doc_year=" + dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    } else
    location.href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>";
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    --></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what " does not work" means here? Thanks

Comment: PLZ CHECK THIS URL

http://w3ondemand.com/dev/itim/%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA/test-pagination/

page reloaded but post not showing According to year

Comment: Please explain your problem better. Do not rely on external sources. Add the error messages that you get to your question text.

Comment: when i select 2016 for see old post page is reloded bt 2016 post nor show 

See this page 
http://w3ondemand.com/dev/itim/%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA/test-pagination/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Year' ) ); ?></option> 
  <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
</select>
```

This code may help you.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: remove your all code and try only this code in your div  then see what happining

Comment: Not working plzz check on url

Comment: i want reload on same page not another